# Check if variable exists and if exists whether is not a nan using Python

Tags: python, validation, variables, types

I would like to improve my coding skill and I struggle with finding a proper solution. I have a variable named `foo`. If `foo` has a numeric value, I need to do some action. However `foo` can be either:

- not set (`NoneType`)
- float with value nan (`math.nan`)
- float with numeric value (`12.3, 16.9` etc.)

I would like to create a **simple** structure that match all cases and best I can think of is this code:

```py
# Validate that foo exists
if foo not None:
# if exists, check if it's not a math.nan
  if not math.isnan(foo):
    # do my desired action
    print("Doing desired action)    
    ...
```

What is the best (in terms of Python philosophy) approach? Thanks

---

Findings so far

- Validating both conditions inside single if fails because `foo` is sometimes not a number `TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType`
- Another approach (more EAFP) is using `try` and `except`, is it more "Pythonic" solution?

```py
try:
  if not math.isnan(foo):
    # do desired action
    print("Doing desired action")    
except TypeError:
   print("foo not yet set")
```

---

Note: If you ask why `foo` is so variable, it's because it's variable taken from a Dataframe. The column has some floats in it, so the column type is `float`. However missing values are displayed as nan (but type is still float). Before loading the dataframe the value is `None` and after load it's `math.nan`

Comment: Be careful with a simple "if foo:", because if foo is 0.0 (but not None), it will not enter the if. You should do "if foo is not None:" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting note, I am adjusting the description.

Comment: How about `if foo is not None and math.isfinite(foo):`?

Comment: ^ This! (Or `if foo is not None and not math.isnan(foo)`) Boolean operations are short-circuiting, so the second condition isn't even evaluated if the first is false

Comment: EAFP vs. LBYL is really a matter of your preference. If you expect you get a TypeError frequently, I'd say LBYL. If not, EAFP.

Comment: It seems like errors I was getting were because if wrongly defined condition in my if. Using any proposed solution works.

If you want, you can post an answer and I will mark is as accepted, otherwise I will answer my question by myself. Thanks